# Mule 4: database : error while calling stored procedure with an identifier with a string of more than 128 chars

Tags: database, stored-procedures, mule

While calling a stored procedure in Mule Database Connector, we pass an argument value

Sample call:

```
call dbo.getAllStudents (@StudentNames='')}
```

The identifier `StudentNames` will be passed as a string that has around 1000 chars.

While making this call, from SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine.

But while calling it from Mule, we are getting the error :

> The identifier that starts with '' is too long. Maximum length is 128

Has anyone faced similar issue before? Kindly help.

Comment: Please share the db operation in Mule and the complete error log.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the syntax expected by the Mule Database connector which should be:

```
{ call procedureName(:param1, :param2, …​, :paramN) }
```

Read the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-stored-procedure#callable-statements-in-stored-procedures for more details